# iOS kills CallKit VoIP app working in background in one minute

Tags: ios, iphone, background, voip, callkit

I have a VoIP app, it uses CallKit and PushKit.
When app is closed and iOS receives a push notification, the app has been woken up in background mode, it answers on call through CallKit and everything works fine, approximately for 50 seconds.
After that iOS kills app with signal 9.
I selected next background modes: **audio** and **voip**, but iOS wants something more to continue infinite background task.

What I forgot to do to prevent killing my app by the system?

P.S. When I call to my app when it's in foreground a call lasts well for hours. Then it's not a memory pressure is the reason for app killing.

Answer (score 2):

After creating VoIP certificate on developer account, In background mode enable below fields

```
1] Audio and Airplay
2] Voice over IP
3] Background fetch
4] Remote notifications
```

Comment: Audio and Airplay not required for WebRTC

Answer (score 1):

When woken up, you need to call [UIApplication beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler]

Comment: Thanks, but I do not need to run any finite length task, I've found the reason of my issue.

Comment: Could you share the reason with me?

Comment: could you share your solution @adnako?

Comment: @famfamfam, one post below - https://stackoverflow.com/a/40652415/952474

Answer (score 1):

I hope you have given permission like below screens.

[image]

[image]

**iOS kills app with signal 9,** that happens due to memory leak or low memory usage.

You can check with instrumentation.

Answer (score 0):

I've found out, reading debug console, that my app utilizes more than 90% CPU answering to a call in background.
This is a reason why iOS kills my app.

Comment: So, what is your solution?

Comment: Hi @adnako, I use CallKit, when user answer the call in background no always but sometimes the apple kill my app with signal 9, did you find any solution? I use only 5% CPU in background..

Comment: Hi @Steven, unfortunately, I do not work on this project anymore, have you used Instruments to check your app doesn't utilizes a lot of memory as well? Or maybe it freezes in the main thread?

Comment: @adnako, Yes, I checked, it use very few memory the only thing that use very high Energy but it is normal for Voip Application as it use network.

Comment: @Steven, sorry, I have no idea. Have you built the app for TestFlight to get crash logs in iPhone Settings?

Comment: @adnako, thanks, I saw that sometimes my app use more than 100% CPU when answering the call in background.. there alot of thread call from pjsip... any idea how calm down the CPU?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the pre build of pristine? That build has a WebRTC bug that was fixed later. It causes too high CPU usage on voice-only calls ([issue5506](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/webrtc/issues/detail?id=5506)). Switch to the WebRTC pod to fix this (https://cocoapods.org/pods/WebRTC).

Moving to the WebRTC pod will take a bit more time than changing the dependency as the API was changed a bit. It wasn't changed much though, so it is doable in a day or two. Switching to the official pod is in any case the way to go as the build from pristine is no longer maintained.